# Add markup before form output for user-login

Tags: forms, theming

I've created a template override for the user login form (user-login.tpl.php) and want to put some content before the form's elements (e.g, header text and copy). Anything you add in user-login.tpl.php become children elements of `<form>`. I want my supporting content outside the form structure.

Is there a template suggestion to get higher up in the processing chain or is this only possible using a specific preprocess hook in template.php or a module? Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks - Jeremy

Comment: an option might be to use the theme's page.tpl and include an if statement that checks for user/login - then include whatever markup you want within...

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a more elegant solution, I used:

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<h1>Header</h1>';
```

What seems odd here is the potential for a lot of markup in your code. I'm relatively new to Drupal, so I'm not sure if this is common practice.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can get the array with {{ element }}

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/template_preprocess_form/8.2.x